# How to pass a file content to a webservice(asmx) from HTML5 FileUpload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I want to pass a file from Html5 file upload to an `ASMX webservice` using `jquery $.ajax`.
I want to know what data type should I use for deserializing uploaded file in webservice.

this is HTML Code:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload"  id="fileToUpload" />
      <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" />
```

Javascript Code:

```
function uploadFile() {
    var ob=new Object();
    ob.name =document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    var Result= JSON.stringify(ob);
    $.ajax(
    { url: "UploadWS.asmx/UploadedFile",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'x':"+Result+"}",
        success: function() { },
        error: function() { alert('error'); }
    });
}
```

Webservice code:

```
public class ExtraInfo
    {
       //What data type write here?
    } 
[WebMethod]
    public void UploadedFile(object x) {
        JavaScriptSerializer Ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ExtraInfo Ext = new ExtraInfo();
        Ext = Ser.Deserialize<ExtraInfo>(x.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function uploadFile() {
    var data = new FormData(),
        file = $("#fileToUpload")[0].files[0];

    data.append( "name", file.name );
    data.append( "size", file.size );
    data.append( "type", file.type );
    data.append( "file", file );

    $.ajax(
    { url: "UploadWS.asmx/UploadedFile",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function() { },
        error: function() { alert('error'); }
    });
}
```

This should appear as a regular upload POST request in your server where `"file"` is the form field name for the uploaded file. I don't know how to do that with ASP.NET though.

Comment: (FileUpload)Request.Form["name"] I believe.

Comment: Excellent answer, you help me a lot.